# exercise 3.3.11 from Chung Kai Lai's "A course in probability theory"

Tags: probability

If X and Y are two independent random variables, E(Y)=$0$ and E($|X|^p$)<$\infty$ for some p$\geq1$, then E($|X+Y|^p$)$\geq$E($|X|^p$).
At least, we know E(XY)=$0$, so I try to find an inequality $|X+Y|^p\geq|X|^p+k*XY$ for some fixed k but failed. Is there any other idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality, you know that:
$$\mathbb{E}( |x+Y|^p ) \ge  \left| \mathbb{E}(x+Y)\right|^p = |x|^p$$
So

$$\mathbb{E}( |X+Y|^p ) = \mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}( |X+Y|^p|X )) \stackrel{\text{Jensen's}}{\ge} \mathbb{E}( \left| X+\mathbb{E}(Y|X) \right|^p ) \stackrel{X,Y \text{ independent}}{=} \mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$$

Comment: Appreciate your help, but could you explain why E($|X+Y|^p$)=E(E($|X+Y|^p|X$))? Actually, in this book conditional probability hasn't been taught in chapter 3 so I think there might be another way without using conditional probability?

Comment: Oh, I have understood your proof now. E($|X+Y|^p$) is treated as a double integration so everything makes sense.

Comment: nice answer.thanks.

Comment: @well: Yeah you got it right. You're welcome.